# Extracting informations from Text file in java

Tags: java, regex, split

I'm writing a program where I need to read a text file and extract some specific strings, the text is written in DOT language and this is an example of the file:

```
digraph G {
node [shape=circle];
0 [xlabel="[]"];
1 [xlabel="[[Text]]"];
0 -> 1 [label="a"];//this
1 -> 2 [label="ab"];//this
1 -> 3 [label="123"];//this
}
```

I want to ignore everything but the lines that have the structure of the commented lines (by `//this`);

Then split every line to three parts, i.e.:

```
 1 -> 2 [label="ab"];
```

saved as a list of strings (or array ...):

```
 [1,2,ab]
```

I tried a lots with `regex` but I couldn't get the expected results.

Comment: Try [`^(\d+)\s+->\s+(\d+)\s+\[\w+="([^"]*)"];\s*//[^/\n]*$`](https://regex101.com/r/mB4tY2/1). The data are in Group 1, 2 and 3.

Comment: since you are parsing a dot file (graph file) maybe there is a java library which can parse dot files and get you the information you need ( nodes, edges, labels) this may be a more robust solution than regex

Comment: thanks for every one ! ,  @stribizhev can you put it in code please !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the regex you can use:

```
(?m)^(\d+)\s+->\s+(\d+)\s+\[\w+="([^"]*)"];\s*//[^/\n]*$
```

See [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/mB4tY2/1).

All the necessary details are held in Group 1, 2 and 3.

See [Java code](http://ideone.com/6KBiLZ):

```
String str = "digraph G {\nnode [shape=circle];\n0 [xlabel=\"[]\"];\n1 [xlabel=\"[[Text]]\"];\n0 -> 1 [label=\"a\"];//this\n1 -> 2 [label=\"ab\"];//this\n1 -> 3 [label=\"123\"];//this\n}"; 
Pattern ptrn = Pattern.compile("(?m)^(\\d+)\\s+->\\s+(\\d+)\\s+\\[\\w+=\"([^\"]*)\"\\];\\s*//[^/\n]*$");
Matcher m = ptrn.matcher(str);
ArrayList<String[]> results = new ArrayList<String[]>();
while (m.find()) {
    results.add(new String[]{m.group(1), m.group(2), m.group(3)});
}
for(int i = 0; i < results.size(); i++) {               // Display results
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(results.get(i)));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

IF you are guaranteed that the line will always be in the format of `a -> b [label="someLabel"];` then I guess you can use a bunch of splits to get what you need:

```
if (outputLine.contains("[label=")) {
    String[] split1 = outputLine.split("->");
    String first = split1[0].replace(" ", ""); // value of 1
    String[] split2 = split1[1].split("\\[label=\"");
    String second = split2[0].replace(" ", ""); // value of 2
    String label = split2[1].replace("\"", "").replace(" ", "").replace("]", "").replace(";", ""); // just the label
    String[] finalArray = {first, second, label};        
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(finalArray)); // [1, 2, ab]
}
```

Seems clunky. Probably a better way to do this.

Comment: thank you @blahfunk , can you add something about ignore the other lines .

Comment: Updated with conditional phrase.